# Window application in Java

Tags: java, window

Can i create a stand alone window application in eclipse using java, which later can be convert into  an .exe file?
please help me regarding this issue

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there exist "*Ahead-of-Time*" compilers such as [**GNU compiler for Java**](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) which serve this purpose.
There are also commercial products such as [**Excelsior Jet**](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jet.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an executable jar, and then wrap it into an exe using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This would be my way of doing it also.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your best option is something like [izpack2exe](http://izpack.org/documentation/izpack-utils.html#windows-executable-wrapper-izpack2exe) - it creates an exe wrapper around a jar file, making it look like a native app to Windows users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create your application into an executable one by using JAR. For that your project convert into a executable jar file. It runs your application like other normal applications.

Answer (score 0):

yes why not you can create stand alone application by using eclipse and you can create jar of this application .

you can create .exe file by using jar wrapper software it is an open source software.